# how to extract data(string) using php?

Tags: php, string

I am new to php and I have no idea how to extract the exact things I want in a string.
for example:

```
Instant Oats Drink - Chocolate Flavour 165g (33g x 5)
```

I want to extract this data so that

```
Name: Instant Oats Drink - Chocolate Flavour
Weight: 165g
number of pack: 5
unit weight: 33g
```

Please give me some help on this question.

Comment: How predictable, uniform and standardized are these strings? It's easy to extract the information from *this particular* string, but I suppose you'll want to do this for a number of different strings automatically...

Comment: [preg_match](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) should do the trick, but to supply this function with correct regular expression we have to know how uniform strings you want to parse are.

Comment: please give some hints..

Comment: ok, the question could be more precise, but why it was downvoted? as far as i understand he tries to parse "cooking recipes", which is a quite interesting task.

Comment: other example like:
Life Bread - Contains Protein 14 slices
Nesvita Cereal Milk (Wheat Milk Formula) 32g x 8
Milk Bar Bun 210g

Comment: it is very hard to extract such information since I have to extract them in one string

Comment: Looks like there are little uniformity in those strings. Do they all come form single source?

Comment: @red23jordan [Inspiration](http://www.ideone.com/C4Rln) for first example. However, it will do nothing good with your second example.

Comment: yes, they came from one source.
I think I need to separate them first?

Comment: From your other data, I can see that Life Bread and Milk Bar Bun does not contain all the data as Instant Oats Drink. This can make it difficult and quite error prone if you are just passing these strings. Are there any other data we can use to contextualize each string?

Comment: the pattern may not equal, so I feel very sad to extract them, 
Can we put some cases for them?
Actually, the source is from here
 http://www3.consumer.org.hk/pricewatch/supermarket-en/

Comment: Well, if you can split those strings into a groups so each group contain only strings in one format, it's possible. If not, it's much more complicated.

Comment: but there are really large amount of data

Comment: Well, another possible solution is to enroll to [Stanford Machine learning class](http://www.ml-class.org) and learn how to write a classification algorithm that would parse your strings or at least classify them to use with a proper regexes :)

Comment: @J0HN Thx first, I saw that there is something about maths? I can't see anything teach me regular expression

Comment: That's about machine learning rather than regexes. The first problem to solve is to recognize the pattern of the particular string, so we can use appropriate regex to parse it. And recognition is a perfect task for the ML algorithms.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4017/discussion-between-j0hn-and-red23jordan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of your strings have that same form you can use regular expressions.

consider that :

```
<?php

    $str = "Instant Oats Drink - Chocolate Flavour 165g (33g x 5)";

    preg_match('/(?P<title>[a-zA-Z\s\-]*)(?P<grammars>[0-9]*g)(\s+\()(?P<portion>[0-9]+g)(\s+x\s+)(?P<times>[0-9]+)(\))/', $str, $m);

    echo "Title : " . $m['title'] . '<br />';
    echo "Grammars : " . $m['grammars'] . '<br />';
    echo "Portion : " . $m['portion'] . '<br />';
    echo "Times : " . $m['times'] . '<br />';

?>
```

Based on @Troy answer you can even use that one that is even sorten

```
<?php

    $str = "Instant Oats Drink - Chocolate Flavour 165g (33g x 5)";

    preg_match('/(?P<title>.*) (?P<grammars>\d+g) \((?P<portion>\d+g) x (?P<times>\d+)\)/', $str, $m);

    echo "Title : " . $m['title'] . '<br />';
    echo "Grammars : " . $m['grammars'] . '<br />';
    echo "Portion : " . $m['portion'] . '<br />';
    echo "Times : " . $m['times'] . '<br />';

?>
```

Comment: it's already been established in the comments that all the strings do not have the same form.

Comment: really?? have you looked at the list of product descriptions on the site he linked?

Comment: should i list out all the possible patterns?

Comment: What you mean ? Can you please be more specific ? :?

Comment: As I dun know regular expression. I just talk what I think :)
the easiest part we can extracted is the weight...since the units of weight g, mL, L ,etc...

Comment: I am realy sorry, but I can't get the meaning of what you say. Propably me english are not so good ! :)

Comment: My english is bad, sorry!
I mean should we extract the weight first. We can search "g", "mL",etc and then get the number

Comment: You are propably thinking in a wrong way. In the above acample the regular expression are stored into $m table and then you can use then in any order you like. Now if you want to extract the units then you have to modify the regular expression it self. If you show us more than one strings then we cold give you more specific answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4018/discussion-between-merianos-nikos-and-red23jordan)

Answer (score 0):

To extract data from strings in php, you can use functions like 
preg_match, explode, ereg

You will need to be more precise about the exact format all the strings will be for this to work correctly, because you need to have a certain format of data you are looking for with thee functions.

Answer (score 0):

If the strings vary as much as you imply, then it's going to be virtually impossible to do it accurately. And that's in any language; nothing about PHP will make it any easier or harder: it's a natural language parsing problem, and those are really tough to automate.

Regex (using the `preg_split()` function) can do the job if the strings are regular, but not for randomly worded strings like these. Each one is its own special case, so you'd have to write a separate bit of code for each one... but in that case, you might just as well have done the splitting manually.

The only way you're going to get this kind of data without manual intervention is if the data provider (ie the site you linked in the comments?) can provide it pre-formatted. They may already have the data split into the required format in their own products database, so if they're willing to provide it, that would work for you.

They'd almost certainly want to charge you for the data, but given the amount of effort involved in doing it manually yourself, it would be probably worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how specific of an answer you are looking for, but here's a regular expression that "parses" your string.  It will work for any string that closely follows the same pattern.

```
<?php
$s = "Instant Oats Drink - Chocolate Flavour 165g (33g x 5)";

preg_match("/(.*) (\d+g) \((\d+g) x (\d+)\)/", $s, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
?>
```

Outputs:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(53) "Instant Oats Drink - Chocolate Flavour 165g (33g x 5)"
  [1]=>
  string(38) "Instant Oats Drink - Chocolate Flavour"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "165g"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "33g"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "5"
}
```